# Security Policy changes throw org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: java, birt, java-security

I have implemented a custom security policy where I have restricted many permissions. I am doing these changes on a birt server. But when I start the birt server after doing these changes, this exception is thrown at the startup :-

```
Servlet [BIRTServerStartupServlet] in web application [] threw load() exceptionorg.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: No implementation defined for org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.verifyAncestory(ClassUtils.java:176)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.verifyAncestory(SPInterface.java:201)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:195)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.<clinit>(BasicHandler.java:43)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:103)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
at com.actuate.schemas.actuate11.javaserver.wsdl.JavaServerAPILocator.<init>(JavaServerAPILocator.java:12)
at com.actuate.javaserver.soap.JavaServerAPILocatorEx.<init>(JavaServerAPILocatorEx.java:34)
at com.actuate.javaserver.utils.EncycServerStubProxy.<init>(EncycServerStubProxy.java:33)
at com.actuate.javaserver.utils.EncycServerStubPool.createPoolItem(EncycServerStubPool.java:31)
at com.actuate.activeportal.utils.ProxyPool.createProxy4Pool(ProxyPool.java:87)
at com.actuate.activeportal.utils.ProxyPool.getProxyObject(ProxyPool.java:77)
at com.actuate.javaserver.Server.getEncycServerStubProxy(Server.java:844)
at com.actuate.javaserver.soap.BIRTServerStartupServlet.sendJavaServerReadyMsgEx(BIRTServerStartupServlet.java:150)
at com.actuate.javaserver.soap.BIRTServerStartupServlet.readyAndHeartbeat(BIRTServerStartupServlet.java:261)
at com.actuate.javaserver.soap.BIRTServerStartupServlet.init(BIRTServerStartupServlet.java:119)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:288)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:285)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:549)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:320)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5349)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I know this error is coming due to the fact that I have a restricted policy, but I can't figure out which permission should I grant the codebase that will allow birt startup to find this jar/implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was doing a mistake with this approach and was giving file permissions only to the directory, and not the subdirectories. So this was a permission issue only. If someone else is facing the same issue, please check your permission file.